# set fixed location of a few specific nodes in visNetwork

Tags: r, graph, visnetwork

How can I fix the location of node 0 to be on the most right, and 5 to be on the most left (5 is ok, what about 0)?

Here is my reproducibale code in R:

```
library(visNetwork)
nodes <- data.frame(id = 0:5,label=0:5)
edges <- data.frame( from=c(0,0,0,1,2,3,1,2,4),to=c(2,3,5,5,5,5,3,4,5))
visNetwork(nodes, edges)%>% visHierarchicalLayout(direction = "LR")  %>% visEdges(arrows = "to")
```

Output:
[image]

Mor explanation:
I need to form a readable graph that one node in my dataset be always on the left (i.e. finish node, shown as 5 here) and one be on the right (i.e. start node, shown as 0). I know to may be possible to use randomseed and try it for lots of combinations, but I am looking for a better solution that fixes the two nodes' positions by their ids to the most extreme left and right.

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with the package that much. But try this:

```r
library(visNetwork)

nodes <- data.frame(id = 0:5,label=0:5)
edges <- data.frame( from=c(0,0,0,1,2,3,1,2,4),to=c(2,3,5,5,5,5,3,4,5))

visNetwork::visIgraphLayout(visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>% visEdges(arrows = "to") %>%
                              visEvents(selectNode = "function(properties) {
      alert('selected nodes ' + this.body.data.nodes.get(properties.nodes[0]).id);}"))
```

You can then manually drag and place the nodes as you like, and wherever you like. Let me know if this workaround is good for you. This is the end result of me placing the way you asked in your question:

[image]
EDIT: Sorry I forgot about the direction of the edges. I've added them.

Comment: Thank you @Toad, this works great in Rstudio and it allows me to move nodes much easier than before. At the moment, as I am using this code in Power BI, I am getting some errors that I need to work on and find a solution. So, I will vote +1 for your answer at the moment but please allow me to wait for other answers for a few days. If there is no other answer I will also accept yours. thanks again and I appreciate your understanding.

Comment: No problem, I agree. Select the best answer. I hope you get some help :)

Comment: thx @Toad 4 the nice code,I have tested this on my network diagram which has about 30 nodes, the issue here is that this JS code is not compatible with visHierarchicalLayout, This means if I have visH...out in the plot, nodes cannot be moved freely and if I remove vis..out then I have to rearrange all nodes manually. So, I guess this JS code works on a small graph nicely. However, I found out that vis..out(direction = "LR",parentCentralization=FALSE,sortMethod="directed",blockShifting = TRUE) provides slightly better layout, but still I am looking for a better answer, thx a lot 4 u code

Comment: Hey no problem. I would have helped if knew more.